# Two types of formulas in one cell - Excel 2013

Tags: windows-8, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Thank you for your time.  I am using Excel formulas for the first time ever and I am stuck (I am sure that I am not using the proper terminology to search and thus cannot find the help I need). It is a silly question I am sure but I need this business plan ready for work on Monday.

I need Line 17 which gets subtracted from line 16 to either have a dollar amount based off of one of two fields depending on which one has data.  How can I accomplish this formula in one field?

```
Total Dollars                     16)    $4,200 (LINE H24 on my spreadsheet)
Less $__10 or ____%               17)    $-  10 (LINE E25 on my spreadsheet)
Average (Line 16 minus Line 17)   18)    $3,780 (LINE H26 on my spreadsheet)
```

OR

```
Total Dollars                     16)    $4,200 (LINE H24 on my spreadsheet)
Less $____ or __20%               17)    $  840 (LINE F25 on my spreadsheet)
Average (Line 16 minus Line 17)   18)    $3,360 (LINE H26 on my spreadsheet)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have defined `H26` to be `=H24-H25`,
and you are looking for a definition of `H25` that is one of two formulas based on `E25` or `F25`,
depending on which one has data.  The answer is to use the `IF()` function.  The general usage is

```
=IF(true_or_false, value_if_first_arg_is_true, value_if_first_arg_is_false)
```

You might use it like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E25), H24*F25/100, E25)
```

i.e., if `E25` is blank, compute `F25` percent of `H24`, otherwise use `E25`.